# Image Gallery using Bootstrap Carousel with thumbnail on side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gallery, carousel

How to Create an Image Gallery Based on Bootstrap Carousel, with Thumbnail on sides for Guidance. 
Please some body provide me some code....

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask people for code. You have google for that :-). If you have anything concrete that doesn't work for some reason, post YOUR solution and ask why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Would have been better had you provided some code you must be working on. Anyways, If I understand you well you intend to create a Galley with thumbnail columns on right.
See if this Implementation using Bootstrap 3 Works for you http://www.bootstrap-tutorials.com/CodeSnippets/Bootstrap-image-gallery-carousel-thumbnail.php
You can alter the position of thumbnail rows by changing the layout...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples .. We've all starting to ask code! May it be the beginning of a lot of work with Bootstrap!

[Gallery Example 1](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-with-gallery-thumbs)

[Gallery Example 2](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/article-carousel-with-images-indicators)

Regards!